# Laravel-Excel export(download) issue in production server but works fine in my devlopment server

Tags: php, laravel, ubuntu, nginx, laravel-excel

I have a Laravel app which should be able to upload and download **`csv`** files to/from my server side database. It works perfectly fine in my local development environment, but when I deployed it to my production server on Vultr.com. my download won't work. upload csv still works fine.

If i click my download button on the web.

In Chrome, it returns

> this site can’t be reached... ERR_INVALID_RESPONSE

In firefox, it returns

> File not found..

In Edge(IE), **it will download a 0 byte partial file.**

**My local dev enviorment is :**
LEMP+PHP5.6+Laravel 5.3

**My production server enviroment is:** 
 Ubuntu 16.10+nginx/1.10.1 (Ubuntu)+php7.0+Laravel5.3. I also test to downgrade PHP from 7.0 to 5.6. the problem still exists.

I did some research online, it seems that this issue relate to php-zip, php-gd modules their correct versions . And most people complain can not download 'xlsx' but old 'xls' and 'csv' works fine.  I've tried multiple times to make sure I have correct/updated  php-zip, php-gd version associate with my php. still no luck. 
my export controller code as :

```
return Excel::create('templete', function($excel) use ($data) {
$excel->sheet('rateTemplete', function($sheet) use ($data)
{
$sheet->fromArray($data);
});
})->download($type); //here $type =csv

//$data was the table generate from the databse, 
//I can use dd($data) before the Excel call to make sure it is alright.
```

Anyone have any idea on this?